# Is it possible to simplify this IF conditional statement in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I'm was trying to create a binary counter, but when I simplified the IF statement, it stopped to work.

This code works:

```
if(counter<500000)
    counter<=counter+1;
else
    counter<=0;
if (counter==0)
    if(LEDR<262143)
        LEDR <= LEDR+1;
    else
        LEDR<=0;
```

this doesn't :

```
if(counter<500000)
    counter<=counter+1;
else
    counter<=0;
if (counter==0 && LEDR<262143)
    LEDR <= LEDR+1;
else
    LEDR<=0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two versions of your code are not equivalent.

In your original version, the `else` part is contained *inside* the `counter == 0` condition, and will be executed when `counter == 0` **and** `LEDR >= 262143`:

```
if (counter==0)
    if(LEDR<262143)
        LEDR <= LEDR+1;
    else // counter must be 0 here
        LEDR<=0;
```

In the "simplified" version, the `else` part will be executed when the *opposite* of `counter == 0 && LEDR < 262143` is true, which is the case if `counter != 0` **or** `LEDR >= 262143`.

```
if (counter==0 && LEDR<262143)
    LEDR <= LEDR+1;
else // counter could be different from 0
    LEDR<=0;
```

You can visualize the difference by listing all possible combinations in a table:

```
counter == 0 | LEDR < 262143 | LEDR <= 0 executed | LEDR <= LEDR+1 executed
             |               | orig.    new       | orig.    new
-------------+---------------+--------------------+------------------------
false        | false         | no      *yes*      | no       no
false        | true          | no      *yes*      | no       no
true         | false         | yes      yes       | no       no
true         | true          | no       no        | yes      yes
```

As you can see, the new version behaves differently when `counter != 0`.

Actually, it is not possible to simplify the desired behaviour to a single `if-else` statement, because this would mean that you can only distinguish between the *two* cases of executing either `LEDR <= LEDR + 1` or `LEDR <= 0`. But in the original code there is a *third* case (when `counter != 0`) where you execute *nothing at all* and leave `LEDR` untouched.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (counter==0)
    if(LEDR<262143)
        LEDR <= LEDR+1;
    else
        LEDR<=0;
```

versus

```
if (counter==0 && LEDR<262143)
    LEDR <= LEDR+1;
else
    LEDR<=0;
```

The first condition for both is the same but you have altered the condition for the second argument.

First example is `if ((counter==0) && !(LEDR<262143))`
Second example is `if !(counter==0 && LEDR<262143)`

Using de-morgans law the second example could be:
`if (counter!=0 || !(LEDR<262143) )` or
`if (counter!=0 ||  (LEDR=<262143))`

Therefore the if statement is not simplified but functionally different.

Comment: I'm sorry,but I don't understand. Why in the first example do you use "=>"  and in the second "!" ?

Comment: I was just pushing the ! through to change the statement so it could be better understood as a comparison.